# How to format dates for use in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am trying to adapt Method 4 in this paper to calculate the duration of many observations, but discounting overlapping dates: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi31/048-31.pdf

For example,  two rows of observations for subject 101 lasting from 2017-03-02 to 2017-03-16 and 2017-03-04 to 2017-03-17 respectively should return a value of only 16 days.

I am getting an error with the dates being 'Invalid numeric data', though, resulting in later errors. I have tried `format startdate yyyymmdd10.;` and `format stopdate yyyymmdd10.;` with no success.

[image: Screenshot of SAS log]

Can anyone help me properly format my dates for use here, or identify any further errors?

**Edit:** Line 80 refers to `do xdate = startdate to stopdate;`.

I am still unable to convert or create the date variables as numeric/date values. I have used the following code:

```
data sasuser.Mdm;
set sasuser.Mdm; 
do xdate = input(Startdate,yymmdd10.) to input(stopdate,yymmdd10.);
    put xdate= yymmdd10.; 
output;
end;
run;
```

To get this output:

````
1    data sasuser.Mdm;
2    set sasuser.Mdm;
3    do xdate = input(Startdate,yymmdd10.) to input(stopdate,yymmdd10.);
4        put xdate= yymmdd10.;
5    output;
6    end;
7    run;

xdate=2017-03-02
xdate=2017-03-03
xdate=2017-03-04
xdate=2017-03-05
xdate=2017-03-06
xdate=2017-03-07
xdate=2017-03-08
xdate=2017-03-09
xdate=2017-03-10
xdate=2017-03-11
xdate=2017-03-12
xdate=2017-03-13
xdate=2017-03-14
xdate=2017-03-15
xdate=2017-03-16
xdate=2017-03-04
xdate=2017-03-05
xdate=2017-03-06
xdate=2017-03-07
xdate=2017-03-08
xdate=2017-03-09
xdate=2017-03-10
xdate=2017-03-11
xdate=2017-03-12
xdate=2017-03-13
xdate=2017-03-14
xdate=2017-03-15
xdate=2017-03-16
xdate=2017-03-17
xdate=2017-03-07
xdate=2017-03-08
xdate=2017-03-09
xdate=2017-03-10
xdate=2017-03-11
xdate=2017-03-12
xdate=2017-03-13
xdate=2017-03-14
xdate=2017-03-15
xdate=2017-03-16
xdate=2017-03-17
xdate=2017-03-18
xdate=2017-03-19
xdate=2017-03-20
xdate=2017-03-21
xdate=2017-02-08
xdate=2017-02-09
xdate=2017-02-10
xdate=2017-02-11
xdate=2017-02-12
xdate=2017-02-13
xdate=2017-02-14
xdate=2017-02-15
xdate=2017-02-16
xdate=2017-02-17
xdate=2017-02-18
xdate=2017-02-19
xdate=2017-02-20
xdate=2017-02-21
xdate=2017-02-22
xdate=2017-02-23
xdate=2017-02-24
xdate=2017-02-23
xdate=2017-02-24
xdate=2017-02-25
xdate=2017-02-26
xdate=2017-02-27
xdate=2017-02-28
xdate=2017-03-01
xdate=2017-03-02
xdate=2017-03-03
xdate=2017-03-04
xdate=2017-03-05
xdate=2017-03-06
xdate=2017-03-07
xdate=2017-03-08
xdate=2017-02-26
xdate=2017-02-28
xdate=2017-03-13
xdate=2017-03-17
xdate=2017-03-25
xdate=2017-03-28
xdate=2017-03-23
xdate=2017-03-24
xdate=2017-03-25
xdate=2017-03-26
xdate=2017-03-27
xdate=2017-03-28
xdate=2017-03-29
xdate=2017-03-30
xdate=2017-03-29
xdate=2017-04-03
xdate=2017-04-04
xdate=2017-04-03
xdate=2017-04-04
xdate=2017-04-05
xdate=2017-04-05
xdate=2017-04-06
xdate=2017-04-06
xdate=2017-04-07
xdate=2017-03-25
xdate=2017-03-26
xdate=2017-03-30
xdate=2017-04-01
xdate=2017-04-02
xdate=2017-04-03
xdate=2017-04-04
xdate=2017-04-08
xdate=2017-04-09
xdate=2017-04-10
xdate=2017-04-11
xdate=2017-04-12
xdate=2017-04-12
xdate=2017-04-13
xdate=2017-04-13
xdate=2017-04-14
xdate=2017-04-15
xdate=2017-04-16
xdate=2017-04-17
xdate=2017-04-18
xdate=2017-04-19
xdate=2017-04-20
xdate=2017-04-21
xdate=2017-04-22
xdate=2017-04-19
xdate=2017-04-23
xdate=2017-04-24
xdate=2017-04-25
xdate=2017-04-26
xdate=2017-04-26
xdate=2017-04-27
xdate=2017-04-28
xdate=2017-05-05
xdate=2017-05-06
xdate=2017-05-16
xdate=2017-05-19
xdate=2017-05-20
xdate=2017-05-21
xdate=2017-05-22
xdate=2017-05-19
xdate=2017-05-20
xdate=2017-05-21
xdate=2017-05-22
xdate=2017-05-23
xdate=2017-05-24
xdate=2017-05-25
xdate=2017-05-26
xdate=2017-05-22
xdate=2017-05-23
xdate=2017-05-24
xdate=2017-05-25
xdate=2017-05-26
xdate=2017-05-27
xdate=2017-05-28
xdate=2017-05-29
xdate=2017-05-30
xdate=2017-05-31
xdate=2017-06-01
xdate=2017-06-02
xdate=2017-06-03
xdate=2017-06-04
xdate=2017-06-05
xdate=2017-06-06
xdate=2017-06-07
xdate=2017-06-08
xdate=2017-06-09
xdate=2017-06-10
xdate=2017-06-11
xdate=2017-06-12
xdate=2017-06-13
xdate=2017-06-14
xdate=2017-06-15
xdate=2017-06-16
xdate=2017-06-17
xdate=2017-06-18
xdate=2017-06-19
xdate=2017-06-20
xdate=2017-06-21
xdate=2017-06-22
xdate=2017-06-23
xdate=2017-06-24
xdate=2017-06-25
xdate=2017-06-26
xdate=2017-06-27
xdate=2017-06-28
xdate=2017-06-29
xdate=2017-06-30
xdate=2017-07-01
xdate=2017-07-02
xdate=2017-07-03
xdate=2017-07-04
xdate=2017-07-05
xdate=2017-07-06
xdate=2017-07-07
xdate=2017-07-08
xdate=2017-07-09
xdate=2017-07-10
xdate=2017-07-11
xdate=2017-07-12
xdate=2017-07-13
xdate=2017-07-14
xdate=2017-07-15
xdate=2017-07-16
xdate=2017-07-17
xdate=2017-07-18
xdate=2017-07-19
xdate=2017-07-20
xdate=2017-07-21
xdate=2017-07-22
xdate=2017-07-23
xdate=2017-07-24
xdate=2017-07-25
xdate=2017-07-26
xdate=2017-07-27
xdate=2017-07-28
xdate=2017-07-29
xdate=2017-07-30
xdate=2017-07-31
xdate=2017-08-01
xdate=2017-08-02
xdate=2017-08-03
xdate=2017-08-04
xdate=2017-08-05
xdate=2017-08-06
xdate=2017-08-07
xdate=2017-08-08
xdate=2017-08-09
xdate=2017-08-10
xdate=2017-08-11
xdate=2017-08-12
xdate=2017-08-13
xdate=2017-08-14
xdate=2017-08-15
xdate=2017-08-16
xdate=2017-08-17
xdate=2017-08-18
xdate=2017-08-19
xdate=2017-08-20
xdate=2017-08-21
xdate=2017-08-22
xdate=2017-08-23
xdate=2017-08-24
xdate=2017-08-25
xdate=2017-08-26
xdate=2017-08-27
xdate=2017-08-28
xdate=2017-08-29
xdate=2017-08-30
xdate=2017-08-31
xdate=2017-09-01
xdate=2017-05-27
xdate=2017-05-28
xdate=2017-05-29
xdate=2017-05-30
xdate=2017-05-31
xdate=2017-06-01
xdate=2017-06-02
xdate=2017-06-03
xdate=2017-06-04
xdate=2017-06-05
xdate=2017-06-06
xdate=2017-06-07
xdate=2017-06-08
xdate=2017-06-09
xdate=2017-06-10
xdate=2017-06-11
xdate=2017-06-12
xdate=2017-06-13
xdate=2017-06-14
xdate=2017-06-15
xdate=2017-06-16
xdate=2017-06-17
xdate=2017-06-18
xdate=2017-06-19
xdate=2017-06-20
xdate=2017-06-21
xdate=2017-06-22
xdate=2017-06-23
xdate=2017-06-24
xdate=2017-06-25
xdate=2017-06-26
xdate=2017-06-27
xdate=2017-06-28
xdate=2017-06-29
xdate=2017-06-30
xdate=2017-07-01
xdate=2017-07-02
xdate=2017-07-03
xdate=2017-07-04
xdate=2017-07-05
xdate=2017-07-06
xdate=2017-07-07
xdate=2017-07-08
xdate=2017-07-09
xdate=2017-07-10
xdate=2017-07-11
xdate=2017-07-12
xdate=2017-07-13
xdate=2017-07-14
xdate=2017-07-15
xdate=2017-07-16
xdate=2017-07-17
xdate=2017-07-18
xdate=2017-07-19
xdate=2017-07-20
xdate=2017-07-21
xdate=2017-07-22
xdate=2017-07-23
xdate=2017-07-24
xdate=2017-07-25
xdate=2017-07-26
xdate=2017-07-27
xdate=2017-07-28
xdate=2017-07-29
xdate=2017-07-30
xdate=2017-07-31
xdate=2017-08-01
xdate=2017-08-02
xdate=2017-08-03
xdate=2017-08-04
xdate=2017-08-05
xdate=2017-08-06
xdate=2017-08-07
xdate=2017-08-08
xdate=2017-08-09
xdate=2017-08-10
xdate=2017-08-11
xdate=2017-08-12
xdate=2017-08-13
xdate=2017-08-14
xdate=2017-08-15
xdate=2017-08-16
xdate=2017-08-17
xdate=2017-08-18
xdate=2017-08-19
xdate=2017-08-20
xdate=2017-08-21
xdate=2017-08-22
xdate=2017-08-23
xdate=2017-08-24
xdate=2017-08-25
xdate=2017-08-26
xdate=2017-08-27
xdate=2017-08-28
xdate=2017-08-29
xdate=2017-08-30
xdate=2017-08-31
xdate=2017-09-01
xdate=2017-06-14
xdate=2017-06-15
xdate=2017-06-16
xdate=2017-06-17
xdate=2017-06-18
xdate=2017-06-19
xdate=2017-06-20
xdate=2017-06-21
xdate=2017-06-22
xdate=2017-06-23
xdate=2017-06-24
xdate=2017-06-25
xdate=2017-06-26
xdate=2017-06-27
xdate=2017-06-28
xdate=2017-06-29
xdate=2017-06-14
xdate=2017-06-15
xdate=2017-06-16
xdate=2017-06-17
xdate=2017-06-18
xdate=2017-06-19
xdate=2017-06-20
xdate=2017-06-21
xdate=2017-06-22
xdate=2017-06-23
xdate=2017-06-24
xdate=2017-06-25
xdate=2017-06-26
xdate=2017-06-27
xdate=2017-06-28
xdate=2017-06-29
xdate=2017-03-27
xdate=2017-04-02
xdate=2017-04-07
xdate=2017-04-08
xdate=2017-04-09
xdate=2017-04-13
xdate=2017-04-14
xdate=2017-04-15
xdate=2017-04-16
xdate=2017-04-17
xdate=2017-04-19
xdate=2017-04-20
xdate=2017-04-21
xdate=2017-04-22
xdate=2017-04-23
xdate=2017-04-24
xdate=2017-04-20
xdate=2017-04-21
xdate=2017-04-22
xdate=2017-04-23
xdate=2017-04-24
xdate=2017-04-25
xdate=2017-04-26
xdate=2017-04-27
xdate=2017-04-28
xdate=2017-04-29
xdate=2017-04-30
xdate=2017-05-01
xdate=2017-05-02
xdate=2017-04-24
xdate=2017-04-25
xdate=2017-04-26
xdate=2017-04-27
xdate=2017-04-28
xdate=2017-04-29
xdate=2017-04-30
xdate=2017-05-01
xdate=2017-05-02
xdate=2017-05-03
xdate=2017-05-04
xdate=2017-05-05
xdate=2017-05-06
xdate=2017-05-07
xdate=2017-05-08
xdate=2017-05-09
xdate=2017-05-10
xdate=2017-05-11
xdate=2017-05-12
xdate=2017-05-13
xdate=2017-05-14
xdate=2017-05-15
xdate=2017-05-16
ERROR: Invalid DO loop control information, either the INITIAL or TO expression is missing or the
       BY expression is missing, zero, or invalid.
SUBJID=106 KEY=106-9 OBS=9 TOTAL=12 STARTDATE=2017-04-25 STOPDATE=  CLASS=Steroid / Diuretic
xdate=20934 _ERROR_=1 _N_=52
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: There were 52 observations read from the data set SASUSER.MDM.
WARNING: The data set SASUSER.MDM may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 431
         observations and 8 variables.
WARNING: Data set SASUSER.MDM was not replaced because this step was stopped.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.38 seconds
      cpu time            0.29 seconds```
````

I don't understand why `input` doesn't appear to be working. Dates are still listed as character strings under column attributes. The `do` part also isn't working as intended.  I'd be grateful for any further guidance.

Comment: I am no expert in SAS, but maybe you should try formatting the dates to ```format startdate ddmmyy10.;``` and ```format stopdate ddmmyy10.;```

Comment: You did a poor job of framing your photograph of the problem in your SAS log.  You appear to have cut off the head in your image.  **What is the line of code at line 80 in the log?** Please post text as text and not as photographs.  Post sample input data and what output you want to get from that data.

Comment: `start_date = input(startDate, yymmdd10.);` to convert your character dates to numeric. You can do it inline as well. `do date = input(startdate, yymmdd10.) to input(stopDate, yymmdd10.);;`

Comment: And data steps are better at these type of calculations rather than SQL.

Comment: Remove the PUT, you only needed to change the line I indicated.

Comment: The input statements aren't changing anything on the main dataset - just for the purposes of the `do` loop.  `xdate` is numeric, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not use the same name in the DATA and SET statement. Then you're always having to rebuild from the start.
2. Convert your start and stop date to SAS dates
3. Remove PUT
4. Add formats to see them displayed as desired
5. Drop old variables to avoid confusion.

**Your two code steps, the data step and SQL do not appear related.** Not sure why you would even need a list of dates for intervals or anything. There are much better ways to calculate an overlap. I think you're putting us through an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where it would be significantly easier to show us what you're attempting to do and people would be able to provide a much better solution.

```
  data sasuser.Mdm2; /*1*/
   set sasuser.Mdm; 
    /*2*/
   start_date = input(startdate, yymmdd10.);
   end_date = input(stopdate, yymmdd10.);

    do xdate = start_date to stop_date;
       output; /*3*/
     end;

    /*4*/
     format start_date end_date xDate yymmdd10.;
     /*5*/
    drop startdate stopdate;

    run;

     *check;
      proc contents data=sasuser.mdm2;
      run;
```

EDIT: Also, if you had some sort of grouping variable to indicate that these were part of the same episode you could then just take the min/max of the dates and subtract them to get the interval duration for starters. Grouping via a data step is trivial.

```
  data want;
  set have;
 by id;
 
 retain episode;
 
 start_date = input(start_date, yymmdd10.);
 end_date = input(stopdate, yymmdd10.);
 prev_stop_date = lag(stopDate);

 if first.id then do;
      episode = 0;
      call missing(prev_stop_date);
 end;

 if not (start_date <=prev_stop_date <= end_date) then episode+1;

 *could add in logic to calculate dates and durations as well depending....;

 run;
```

Comment: If they have multiple records in the initial dataset, then it's possible this is the simplest way to do the "how many days" calculation; there're certainly faster ways, but I wouldn't fault someone who was a relatively novice programmer from taking this route, as it's fairly low risk.

Comment: Yeah but as soon as your data set is larger this blows up. I use this method when looking at drug dosing stuff quite a bit and it works but doesn't scale at all.

Comment: This is really clear, thanks. I'll bear the 'xy problem' in mind for future questions -- my main goal is to find durations while discounting overlapping dates for many patients. The method I'm using is based on what I found in the http://support.sas.com site, but I am always open to better solutions. 

Regarding grouping variables, I do have an "OBS" column that numbers each instance of drug use. I also have a "KEY" column which appends the OBS to the subject ID (SUBJID).

I am likely to have to do this again with larger datasets in the future. What would you recommend in this case?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your SAS log is complaining about this statement.

```
do xdate=startdate to stopdate;
```

Because STARTDATE and STOPDATE are character strings instead of dates.

Make sure to create your date values as dates instead of character strings.

Answer (score 1):

Tom's correct, of course, the `startdate` and `stopdate` seem to be characters.

To properly use this, do something like this (only the do loop is relevant for you, the rest is to show it working):

```
data _null_;
  startdate = '2017-03-02';
  stopdate  = '2017-03-16';
  do xdate = input(Startdate,yymmdd10.) to input(stopdate,yymmdd10.);
    put xdate= yymmdd10.; *just put to the log to see what you are getting;
  end;
run;
```

`input` will convert the text to a numeric value.  Do realize you have to format that `xdate` as a date format if you want to be able to view it - if you're just using it as an input, though, you can leave the formatting off.