# Finding the total duration of multiple overlapping "start date" and "end date" entries, before a cut-off date?

Tags: date, sas, overlap, duration

I have a list of subjects with multiple overlapping entries in the following format:

```
     ID     startdate    stopdate     cutoffdate

1    101    07MAR2014    07MAR2014    14MAR2014
2    105    30MAR2017    03APR2017    07APR2017
3    105    03APR2017    09APR2017    07APR2017
```

I have previously used SAS to count the total duration for each subject. I used the code described in the SAS documentation [here](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi31/048-31.pdf), and adapted in another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64175870/7804160). The output using this method would be 1 day for subject 101 and 11 days for subject 105.

Now I have a cut-off date in the far right column. I want my code to disregard days beyond this; i.e. the output would then become 1 day for subject 101 and 9 days for subject 105.

How do I calculate the duration of these overlapping date entries for each subject, but disregard any dates which fall beyond the cut-off date?

Code from prior answer:

```
 data want;
  set have;
 by id;
 
 retain episode;
 
 start_date = input(start_date, yymmdd10.);
 end_date = input(stopdate, yymmdd10.);
 prev_stop_date = lag(stopDate);

 if first.id then do;
      episode = 0;
      call missing(prev_stop_date);
 end;

 if not (start_date <=prev_stop_date <= end_date) then episode+1;

 *could add in logic to calculate dates and durations as well depending....;

 run;
```

Answer (score 0):

A see the solution with some logic inside for correct calculation with overlapped dates:

```
data test;
  input ID startdate : date9. stopdate : date9. cutoffdate : date9.;
  format startdate stopdate cutoffdate date9.;
  datalines;
  101 07MAR2014 07MAR2014 14MAR2014
  105 30MAR2017 03APR2017 07APR2017
  105 03APR2017 09APR2017 07APR2017
  ;
run;

proc sort data=test;
  by ID startdate;
data want (keep=ID datediff);
  set test;
  by ID startdate;
  retain startd stopd datediff;

  if first.ID then do;
    startd = startdate;
    stopd = stopdate;
    if stopdate LT cutoffdate then datediff=stopdate - startdate + 1;
      else datediff=cutoffdate - startdate + 1;
  end;
  else do;
    if startdate LE stopd and startdate GE startd then
        startd = stopd;
    if stopdate GE startd and stopdate LE cutoffdate then
        stopd = stopdate;
    else if stopdate GE startdate and stopdate GT cutoffdate then
        stopd = cutoffdate;

    datediff = datediff + stopd - startd;
  end;

  if last.ID then output;
run;
```

This code, of course, could be optimized. Please check my logic!

Such code produces:

```
ID      datediff
––––––––––––––--
101            1
105            9
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally what I'd do is create a new `stopdate` variable which was defined as

```
stopdate_cut = min(stopdate,cutoffdate);
```

Then your original code will work (just with this new variable).  Make sure to also test `startdate`, presumably delete the entire row if `startdate` is more than `cutoffdate` (`where startdate le cutoffdate` might be the easiest).

Just to be clear, the original code didn't calculate durations, so I'll add that in here:

```
data final;
  set want;
  by id episode;
  if first.episode then duration=1;
  duration+(stopdate-startdate);
  if last.episode then output;  
run;
```

That gives 1 and 11.  You might need slightly more code depending on your data.

To add the cutoff, simply add these two lines (the `where` here isn't doing anything in the example data, but it could be needed.)

```
data final;
  set want;
  by id episode;
  where startdate le cutoffdate;
  stopdate_cut = min(stopdate,cutoffdate);
  if first.episode then duration=1;
  duration+(stopdate_cut-startdate);
  if last.episode then output;  
run;
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this would go in your code right before the `lag(stopdate)` line, and everything after this you'd replace `stopdate` with `stopdate_cut`, including that lag.  (Also, be aware of how `min` treats missing values, if `stopdate` can ever be missing, and test for it if need be.)

Comment: Simple lag(stopdate) or min(stopdate,cutoffdate) does not solve the problem with windows in dates. Some logic is required.

Comment: @crow16384 The example code didn't calculate durations, but I assume OP actually had modified it to do so.  If OP did, then this should work fine (for the simple data example - of course, who knows what the actual data is, and what extra logic could be needed).  I added the (trivial) duration calculations to my answer to show how it could be used.

Comment: Look https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/079-2009.pdf

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with possibly overlapping date ranges within a group there is also a possibility you have some gaps.

Because dates are integers in a limited domain you can use a temporary array that is key-indexed with the date and *paint* values across the range.  At the end of the group the number of values in the array is the number of days that fell within a range.

Example:

```
* generate some data;

data have;
  call streaminit(2020);

  length id start_date end_date limit_date step 8;
  do id = 1 to 20;
    end_date = '01jan2015'd;
    limit_date = '30sep2016'd;

    do _n_ = 1 to rand('integer', 1, 7);
      step  = rand('integer', -10,60); * data generator diagnostic;
      range = rand('integer', 30); * data generator diagnostic;

      start_date = end_date + step;
      end_date = start_date + range;

      output;
    end;
  end;
  format start_date end_date limit_date date9.;
run;

* d1 to d2 should cover all expected dates;

%let d1 = %sysevalf("01JAN2000"D);
%let d2 = %sysevalf("31DEC2100"D);

* evaluate the date range coverage for each id;

data want;
  array dates[&d1:&d2] _temporary_; * the canvas onto which values are painted;

  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    do _n_ = start_date to end_date;
      if _n_ > limit_date then leave;
      if dates(_n_) = 1 then overlap_days+1;
      dates(_n_) + 1;                           * paint on that canvas;
    end;
    ranges_count + 1;
  end;

  * compute total range and portions;

  do _n_ = lbound(dates) to hbound(dates);
    if missing(dates(_n_)) then continue;

    days + 1;
    if missing(all_start_date) then all_start_date =_n_;
    all_end_date = _n_;

    if _n_ > all_start_date and dif(_n_) > 1 then gaps + 1;
  end;

  all_days = all_end_date - all_start_date + 1;
  coverage = days / all_days;

  OUTPUT;

  call missing(of _all_, of dates(*));

  format all_start_date all_end_date date9. coverage percent6.2;

  keep id days all_: ranges_count overlap_days gaps cover:;
run;
```

Produces
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here more possible conditions are set:

```
data have;
  input ID startdate : date9. stopdate : date9. cutoffdate : date9.;
  format startdate stopdate cutoffdate date9.;
  datalines;
  101 07MAR2014 07MAR2014 14MAR2014
  105 30MAR2017 03APR2017 07APR2017
  105 03APR2017 09APR2017 07APR2017
  106 12MAY2018 18MAY2018 01JUL2018
  106 15MAY2018 20MAY2018 01JUL2018
  106 25MAY2018 28MAY2018 01JUL2018
  107 01JAN2005 09JAN2005 01FEB2005
  107 05JAN2005 20JAN2005 01FEB2005 
  107 16JAN2005 18JAN2005 01FEB2005 
  107 26JAN2005 31JAN2005 01FEB2005 
  ;
run;
```

Firstly, it is necessary to consider insider of cutoffdate, so min(stopdate,cutoffdate) is used;  Secondly, need to consider if the period is complete within the previous record; Thirdly, if startdate is previous stopdate, it is needed to +1, here is '_stop+1' in ifn function.

```
data want;
   set have ;
   by id startdate notsorted;
   retain total;
   _start=lag(startdate);_stop=lag(stopdate);
   if first.id then total=min(stopdate,cutoffdate)-startdate+1;
   else do;
      if _start<=startdate and stopdate<=_stop then return;  
     total=total+min(stopdate,cutoffdate)-ifn(_stop<startdate,startdate,_stop+1)+1;
   end;
   if last.id then output;
   drop _:;
run;


The SAS System 

Obs ID startdate stopdate cutoffdate total 
1 101 07MAR2014 07MAR2014 14MAR2014 1 
2 105 03APR2017 09APR2017 07APR2017 9 
3 106 25MAY2018 28MAY2018 01JUL2018 13 
4 107 26JAN2005 31JAN2005 01FEB2005 26
```